# Application is not start when my Sony Xperia C Device restart(Reboot)

Tags: android, android-broadcast

Broadcast Receiver class reciecve when BOOT_COMPLETED action is called from manifest i.e, whenever the devices is restart I also given the permission in Manifest.
   android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"

The BroadcastReceiver class is follow as -

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);  
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(i);  

     }

}
```

In this app we are trying to start the app as soon as device restart every time
It work fine is all the devices but not in Sony xperia c